# Failover on a DNS with more that 1 query

Tags: domain-name-system

I want to make something like this (on Amazon 53):

- I have a domain (e.g. example.com) that points to multiple IPs

  - e.g. example.com A 8.8.8.5
                 8.8.8.4
                 8.8.8.3
                 8.8.8.2
                 8.8.8.1
- And I want DNS to respond with random IPs

BUT, what I want to do and I don't know how:

- If `8.8.8.5` is not responding, to not include it in the response any more.

  - i.e. if `8.8.8.5` is unresponsive, only include `8.8.8.4`, `8.8.8.3`, `8.8.8.2` and `8.8.8.1` (randomized) in the response.

Could you please let me know how to do this?

Regards, Ciprian

Answer (score 2):

Amazon 53 supports Health checks. Define a Health check to check your domain on each IP and Amazon will exclude this IP if something goes wrong.

Comment: This is the only solution? If I have 1000 IPs what should I do? I'll pay a lots for every single check :(

Comment: If you want to stuck with Amazon Route 53 then yes this is the way to go. 

Alternatively you can set up your own DNS Server (Say PowerDNS which stores Resource records in a Mysql database), implement your own Health checks and add / remove records (A Records in your case) in   PowerDNS database. 

I can't think something else.